# yearmon with missing values as characters in R

Tags: r, date, data.table, zoo

I have a large dataset in R, in data.table, where some columns contain dates in the yyyy-mm format. Some of these have missing values, denoted as "ND".

I am looking for a comprehensive solution to use as.yearmon(x) of the "zoo" package on these columns in the "if" section of data.table without it generating the following error: 
"Error in as.yearmon.character(x) : yearmon variable can only have one format"

as.yearmon(x) works fine on a column which contains only dates in the yyyy-mm format and it also works fine on a column containing no dates, only text such as "ND", in which case it gives only NA's. The problem occurs when these are combined such that there is a column which has both dates and other text such as "ND", at which point the aforementioned Error occurs.

One way around this would be to create new columns where the "ND"s are replaced by NA's, but this seems to take a lot of code over and over as it is a very large dataset. I would also prefer it if the original "x" is not altered, as it is used for many other purposes as well.

Here is some code to clarify:

```
x <- c("2016-06","2016-07","ND")
DT <- data.table(x)
DT[as.yearmon(DT$x) > as.yearmon("2016-01") , y := 1]
```

In some way I want as.yearmon(x) to give as output:

```
DT$y
1 1 NA
```

Comment: I think that (1) you should use R's NA format instead of trying to work with your own `is.na(x) <- (x == "ND")` and (2) you should store your data as yearmon instead of fiddling around converting it on the fly `DT = data.table(x = as.yearmon(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a logical index with `grep` in the `i` and check whether the `yearmon` of 'x' is greater than that of '2016-01', convert to `integer` and assign (`:=`) is as new column 'y'.

```
DT[!grepl("[[:alpha:]]+", x), y := as.integer(as.yearmon(x) > as.yearmon("2016-01")) ]
DT$y
#[1]  1  1 NA
```

---

Or as @Frank mentioned in the comments, we can use `%like%`

```
DT[!x %like% "ND", y := as.integer(as.yearmon(x) > as.yearmon("2016-01")) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to transform the "NDs" into NA beforehand. For example:

```
x <- as.yearmon(gsub("ND", NA, c("2016-06","2016-07","ND"), fixed=TRUE))
DT <- data.table(x)
DT[as.yearmon(x) > as.yearmon("2016-01") , y := 1]
```

or within the data.table

```
x <- c("2016-06","2016-07","ND")
DT <- data.table(x)
DT[, .(x=as.yearmon(gsub("ND", NA, c("2016-06","2016-07","ND"), fixed=TRUE)))
   ][x > as.yearmon("2016-01"), y := 1][]
```

Which both return

```
DT
          x  y
1: Jun 2016  1
2: Jul 2016  1
3:     <NA> NA
```